# I have two byte[] , I need to compare strings between this byte [], does it require explicit conversion new String(byte[])

Tags: java, string, arrays

my objective is to compare the two string values in two byte array. it actually requires two new string object creation for to use contains method. Is it the choice of right or is there any way to use optimize way without new keyword usage.

```
if(new String(bSourceStr).contains(new String(dest))) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: (Off-topic): your code can just be: `return new String(bSourceStr).contains(new String(dest))` - no need for an `if` statement.

Comment: Are you sure your two byte arrays are actually representable as Strings? What encoding are your bytes in?

Comment: As @DanielPryden intimates, the encoding is very important. If the encoding used multiple bytes to represent a single character, than a naive byte-level search would be insufficient. (I'm assuming that you're looking for a "substring" since that's what your code example shows).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays.equals()` if you want to compare the actual content of arrays that contain primitive types values (like byte).

```
String str1="Hello";
String str2="Hello";
byte[] aa = str1.getBytes();
byte[] bb = str2.getBytes();
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(aa, bb));
```

Use `Arrays.deepEquals` for comparison of arrays that contain objects.

Also you for comparing two Byte objects numerically you can use `java.lang.Byte.compareTo(Byte anotherByte)`. Take a look ar this **[Java.lang.Byte.compareTo() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/byte_compareto.htm)**

Comment: Based on his code example, rather than compare for equality, it looks like he wants to find a matching subset of the bytes.

Comment: @GregKopff using `java.lang.Byte.compareTo(Byte anotherByte). ` we can comparing two Byte objects numerically right

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan thanks for your suggestion.  But i am looking the aspect of performance / optimization way . My doubt is do we require conversion of string?  i am trying to compare a string in Bytes. i think compareTo() , requires loop to compare all bytes.

Comment: @androidgalaxyman for checking the bytes no need of converting again to string

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan , mate assume i am having byte1 [] for string1 "i am the one" , byte2 [] for string2 "he" , if we need to compare means the compareTo() no useful. i hope this is the best way to use for this case here  return new String(bSourceStr).contains(new String(dest)).  anyway we can't prevent the string object creation.

Comment: @androidgalaxyman you can use `Arrays.equals(aa, bb);` then, so no need of creating any string objects

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan , Hi Mate, thanks for your suggestion. return Arrays.equals(aa, bb); not equal to  return new String(bSourceStr).contains(new String(dest)) . Because  return new String(bSourceStr).contains(new String(dest)) we are searching if the string present or not.

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan assume string 1 ="iam the one" string2= "he", if you want to compare string2 inside the string1. The Arrays.equals(aa, bb) not useful. It only compares the bytes which equal to each other. so that for my case , it returns false.